# How can I make name places with individual names

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, cs5

We have designed a name place. But there are 350 people. Is there a way to get InDesign to populate 350 versions of this file?

Is there some way to dynamically populate a placeholder with CSV information or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Save the names in CSV format and import in InDesign via 'Window → Utilities → Data Merge'
- Define where in your template the names should be injected
- Detailed info at https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html
- Video https://youtu.be/B_qDD0hZspQ